# Why is this section of my batch script not being executed?

Tags: batch-file

I'm having a problem calling a specific section of my batch script. The goal is to run this script and have it install the given executables and run some commands:

```
@ECHO OFF

ECHO 1. 32-bit
ECHO 2. 64-bit
SET /P INSTALL="Please choose the correct installation: "
SET /P PROXY="Enter proxy gateway path if applicable to your environment: "
2>NUL CALL :CASE_%INSTALL%
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 CALL :ERROR
REM CASE_%INSTALL% or ERROR returns to here
ECHO Done.
PAUSE
EXIT \B

:CASE_1
    REM Install NodeJS 32-bit
    CALL node-v4.4.7-x86.msi
    REM Install Ruby
    CALL rubyinstaller-2.3.1.exe
    GOTO NEXT_TASK
:CASE_2
    REM Install NodeJS 64-bit
    CALL node-v4.4.7-x64.msi
    REM Install Ruby
    CALL rubyinstaller-2.3.1-x64.exe
    GOTO NEXT_TASK
:NEXT_TASK
    REM Install SASS CSS precompiler (v3.4.19)
    CALL gem install sass --http-proxy %PROXY%
    REM Install Compass CSS plug-in (v1.0.3)
    CALL gem install compass --http-proxy %PROXY%
    REM Run Node package install
    CD ..
    IF NOT "%PROXY%"=="" (
        CALL npm config set proxy %PROXY%
        CALL npm config set https-proxy %PROXY%
    )
    CALL npm install
    REM Instal grunt globally
    CALL npm install -g grunt
    REM Install jshint globally because of warning
    CALL npm install -g jshint
    GOTO END_CASE
:ERROR
    ECHO Unable to complete installation of tools
    GOTO END_CASE
:END_CASE
    VER > NUL
    GOTO:EOF
```

This will execute either `CASE_1` or `CASE_2` perfectly, depending on what the user chooses. NodeJS is installed, and so is Ruby. Then, when it reaches the end of one of those sections, I will get this output:

```
Done.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

The script never follows the `GOTO` to run `NEXT_TASK`, and thus never installs SASS or Compass and also doesn't run the npm commands.

> I have noticed that running this script twice and *skipping the NodeJS installation* on the *second* run actually executes the `NEXT_TASK` section correctly... - this leads me to believe there's some sort of timing issue going on here.

Other things I have tried:

- Replacing the `GOTO`s with `CALL`s (does not behave correctly)
- Replacing the section names referenced by `GOTO` to use the format `:{Section}` (no change)
- Replacing the `CALL`s before the Node and Ruby executable with `START /WAIT` (doesn't seem like that makes any difference)

So, I'm stumped. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you put `call` in front of executables? `call` is intended to call other batch files or batch sub-routines...

Comment: I saw it does the same thing as `START /WAIT` and I wanted to wait for the executable to complete before continuing - it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: You don't need anything for `.exe` files; for `.msi` I think you need `start /WAIT`; I'd not use `call` for either file types...

Comment: You should remove or comment out `@echo off` for debugging; since you are using file names (= relative paths) only, some items might not be found... You could also place some `echo` commands in the `:NEXT_TASK` section, so you see if it is truly skipped...

Comment: I'll try making those changes. I've verified all files are found by the script.

Comment: Ah, and remove the `2>NUL` redirection from the line `2>NUL CALL :CASE_%INSTALL%` for debugging, to not suppress any error messages...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving my problem (using a workaround) by breaking the script into two separate scripts. Unfortunately, I'm unable to call one script from the other and be certain that the `gem` and `npm` commands will be set (even through the use of `START` to create a new environment, which was surprising to me), so this is my solution. Thanks to @aschipfl for pointing out the unnecessary use of `CALL` when referencing executables.

*install_tools.bat* (Run first)

```
@ECHO OFF

ECHO 1. 32-bit
ECHO 2. 64-bit
SET /P INSTALL="Please choose the correct installation: "
2>NUL CALL :CASE_%INSTALL%
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 CALL :ERROR
REM CASE_%INSTALL% returns to here
PAUSE
EXIT

:CASE_1
    REM Install NodeJS 32-bit
    START "" /W node-v4.4.7-x86.msi
    REM Install Ruby
    rubyinstaller-2.3.1.exe
    GOTO SUCCESS

:CASE_2
    REM Install NodeJS 64-bit
    START "" /W node-v4.4.7-x64.msi
    REM Install Ruby
    rubyinstaller-2.3.1-x64.exe
    GOTO SUCCESS

:ERROR
    ECHO.
    ECHO Unable to complete installation of tools
    GOTO END_CASE

:SUCCESS
    ECHO.
    ECHO Done. Please run init_tools.bat.
    GOTO END_CASE

:END_CASE
    VER > NUL
    GOTO:EOF
```

*init_tools.bat* (Run second)

```
@ECHO OFF

SET /P PROXY="Enter proxy gateway path if applicable to your environment: "

REM Install SASS CSS precompiler (v3.4.19)
CALL gem install sass --http-proxy %PROXY%
REM Install Compass CSS plug-in (v1.0.3)
CALL gem install compass --http-proxy %PROXY%
REM Run Node package install
CD ..
IF NOT "%PROXY%"=="" (
    CALL npm config set proxy %PROXY%
    CALL npm config set https-proxy %PROXY%
)
CALL npm install
REM Instal grunt globally
CALL npm install -g grunt
REM Install jshint globally because of warning
CALL npm install -g jshint

ECHO.
ECHO Tools initialized.
PAUSE
EXIT
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code and let me know if it works, and what the error is. You might need to increase timeout after 1st call.

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
ECHO 1. 32-bit
ECHO 2. 64-bit
SET /P INSTALL="Please choose the correct installation: "
SET /P PROXY="Enter proxy gateway path if applicable to your environment: "
CALL :CASE_%INSTALL%
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (ECHO Unable to complete ruby installation & GOTO :END
) ELSE (TIMEOUT /t 3 /nobreak >nul
    set PATH="%PATH%;C:\Ruby23-x64\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\"
    CALL :NEXT_TASK
    IF ERRORLEVEL 1 ECHO Unable to complete other tools installation & GOTO :END)
ECHO Installation completed.

:END
TIMEOUT /t 5 /nobreak >nul
EXIT /B

:CASE_1
    REM Install NodeJS 32-bit
    START "" /W node-v4.4.7-x86.msi
    REM Install Ruby
    rubyinstaller-2.3.1.exe
    EXIT /B

:CASE_2
    REM Install NodeJS 64-bit
    START "" /W node-v4.4.7-x64.msi
    REM Install Ruby
    rubyinstaller-2.3.1-x64.exe
    EXIT /B

:NEXT_TASK
    REM Install SASS CSS precompiler (v3.4.19)
    START "" /W gem install sass --http-proxy %PROXY%
    REM Install Compass CSS plug-in (v1.0.3)
    START "" /W gem install compass --http-proxy %PROXY%
    REM Run Node package install
    CD ..
    IF NOT "%PROXY%"=="" (
        START "" /W /B npm config set proxy %PROXY%
        START "" /W /B npm config set https-proxy %PROXY%
    )
    START "" /W npm install
    REM Instal grunt globally
    START "" /W npm install -g grunt
    REM Install jshint globally because of warning
    START "" /W npm install -g jshint
    EXIT /B
```

Comment: Thanks for trying. While this does at least try to run the `npm` and `gem` commands, Windows does not see them as valid commands during run-time of the script.

Comment: What are your Ruby and NodeJS executable paths after installing both packages? Pls type them here.

Comment: `C:\Ruby23-x64\bin` and `C:\Program Files\nodejs` - however, if the person installing Ruby and NodeJS decides to change the default paths, these could be different.

Comment: Try the updated script above (untested), tweak START params if needed upon results. As well you can try Cmd /e or Call instead of Start in :NEXT_TASK block to test the effect. If you decide to dynamically change install paths, this would require to add a search block to the script to find out where the 2 executables were installed. The reason is, PATH env var is updated when you restart Cmd, hence it needs to be set temporarily within the script to avoid splitting it into 2 batches. Let me know any errors.

Comment: No, due to the possibility of path differences as I mentioned previously. Don't bother spending any more time on it. Thanks for trying.